# черешены или черешины?

Tags: орфография

Помогите разобраться! Всё дело в беглой гласной? Как всё-таки верно?

Comment: Что это за слово такое - и откуда в нем ***беглая*** гласная?!  А вообще - см. тут. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F

Comment: Спасибо. Я знаю, что так не говорят. Но такой замысел.

Comment: «Так не говорят» про что?

Comment: Тогда вам надо было написать, что речь идет о множественном числе слова, означающего то-то и то-то.  Или хотя бы пример использования дать. А вы, напротив, словами про "беглу гласную" все запутали окончательно.

Answer (score 3):

Существует ли слово «черешина»?

Раньше существовало. **Из словаря Даля:**  ЧЕРЕШНЯ ж. род крупной, сладкой вишни, Черешневое варенье. Черешник, черешняк черешневый сад. Черешневка, черешневая наливка; **черешина,** **одно такое дерево; || одна ягодка.**

Вишня и черешня очень похожи. Это и дерево,  и плод такого дерева. Но вот в статье для вишни указано слово **«вишенка»**, есть даже устойчивый оборот «вишенка на торте», а слова «черешенка»  нет.

А как же тогда назвать одну ягоду черешни? Даль называл ее «черешина». Вероятно,  здесь использован **суффикс единичности ИН**, сравнить: горох – горошина. Но так как  одна ягода вишни называется «вишенка», то назовем ягоду черешни так же –  **«черешенка».**

Слово "вишенка" образуется  следующим образом: вишн/я – вишен/ка, где К – суффикс единичности, Е – **беглая гласная.**

Сравнить: песн/я – песен/к/а, беглая гласная Е; малин/а – малин/к/а, морковь – морков/к/а, суффикс единичности К.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Итак, **черешенка** – это нормативное название для одной  ягоды (оказывается, в словарях оно всё-таки есть). Или **черешина**, если очень нужно именно такое название. Хотя оно ненормативное, но соответствует словарю Даля, а также образовано по действующим правилам.

Comment: А не отнести ли эту гласную к "чередующимся"? Ведь в естественной паре "черешина-черешенка" гласная никуда не "убегает". Слово "черешина" выглядит вполне _нормативным_ (я бы не удивился, услышав его по отношению к отдельной ягоде; оно есть и в Словаре синонимов Трушина), в отличие от практикуемого канцеляризма "сосуля".

Comment: Черешн/я – череш/ин/а – череш/ин/к/а.  В этой схеме усечение основы при образовании слова «черешина», в этом можно увидеть ненормативность и использование нестандартной схемы образования. Но это единственный недостаток,  так  как значение суффиксов подходит и  легко узнается пользователями в речи (бусы – бусина – бусинка, горох – горошина – горошинка). Получится парный вариант с разным морфемным составом: черешен/к/а - череш/ин/к/а.

Answer (score 1):

Ээээ...
В значении "одна штука ягоды", что бы там ни говорил Даль, - ***черешина***.  Как окказиональное образование.
Черешена здесь противоречило бы семантики суффикса.

Я попытаюсь внести ясность в ответ Sharon (скажу сразу, он мне понравился только тем, что вопрос был понят правьно) и сопоставить ситуацию с "беглой гласной" с реальностю.

Итак. В слове Черешня действительно есть беглый гласный Е (р. мн. - черешен), историческая форма - черешьня (см. Фасмер). Но это корневой гласный (очень древний суффикс (ь)н - давно перестал выделяться как самостоятельный морф), он не имеет - и не может иметь отношения к способу образования "черешина". В значении же "единица", "штука" используется только "ин" в котором никакой беглой гласной нет: - ***макаронина, картофелина, морковина***. Обратных примеров я не знаю.

Если слово "черешена" и попало в какие-то словари (кроме далевского, который вообще изобилует примерами вольной орфографии), то, скорее всего, по недоразумению, ибо слво  оказиональное, за ним могли не уследить.

Написал все только ради истории с беглой гласной.

Comment: *что бы там не говорил Даль* — может, Вы хотели сказать "что бы там ни говорил Даль"? (Я бы поправил сам, но не уверен, поскольку не понимаю смысла всего этого предложения). И в конце предложения или какие-то слова пропущены, или должно быть "семантике" (в Д.П.)

Comment: Отдельно замечу, что "черешена" не попала ни в один словарь, насколько мне известно. И, конечно, у Даля "черешина" (об этом говорится в ответе Sharon). Поэтому смысл Вашего ответа в остальном (кроме беглой гласной) совершенно неясен.

Comment: @grizzly - *Вы хотели сказать "что бы там ни говорил Даль"* - да, конечно, спасибо.  ПС *Удивлен своему пяпу. Не характерная для меня ошибка*.

Comment: *Отдельно замечу, что "черешена" не попала ни в один словарь,* - Я так Sharon понял, что она из "черешенка" выводит "черешена", а иначе зачем всё это у неё? Впрочем, не буду настаивать, похоже я не в лучшей форме сегодня ))))

Comment: *Поэтому смысл Вашего ответа в остальном (кроме беглой гласной) совершенно неясен* - да по сути только о ней, беглой, и речь. Она меня и сподвигла. Беглый гласный есть в корне, но не в суффиксе, плэтому написание "черешена" противоречит общим моделям.